# Need build webhooks in Saleforce to recieve third party server alerts

Tags: apex, apex-webservice, website-integration

I need some guidance/code snippet in developing a webhooks in Salesforce to receive alerts from third party server.

**Requirements.**

In our case, Insideview will send alerts to Salesforce whenever they update company or person information in their database.

In Salesforce, we need to read alerts and make necessary changes in our objects(accounts and object).

If you need more information, please let me know.  I am just looking for high-level technical information on how to implement with some example.

Comment: Read up on RestResource

Comment: I don't think this question necessarily needs to be closed...OP is not asking us for a complete integration developed for them, simply a high level overview.

Comment: I agree with @AdrianLarson. The answers below are fine for a question like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salesforce support the way to get the request and provide the response from third party sites. It is RestResource.

**Pre-requisite:**

1. Authentication with Salesforce.OR You can setup force.con site and expose that class so, you can invoke it without authentication.
2. RestResource annotated class.

**Go through below link to setup rest resource:-**

[Add a Class as a REST Resource](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apex_workbook.meta/apex_workbook/apex_rest_1.htm)

**A sample class look like this:-**

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Merchandise/*')
global with sharing class MerchandiseManager {

    @HttpGet
    global static Merchandise__c getMerchandiseById() {
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;        
        String merchId = req.requestURI.substring(
                                  req.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        Merchandise__c result = 
                       [SELECT Name,Description__c,Price__c,Total_Inventory__c
                        FROM Merchandise__c 
                        WHERE Id = :merchId];
        return result;
    }

    @HttpPost
    global static String createMerchandise(String name,
        String description, Decimal price, Double inventory) {
        Merchandise__c m = new Merchandise__c(
            Name=name,
            Description__c=description,
            Price__c=price,
            Total_Inventory__c=inventory);
        insert m;
        return m.Id;
    }
}
```

You can also generate wsdl from above and consume it on third party site.

**Other thing:-**
If you are looking for standard operations in Salesforce ex: create/update a record, delete record etc. This available natively. Below are some sample code:-

- [Sample create Call](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sample_create_call.htm)
- [Sample update Call](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sample_update_call.htm)

There is a [wsdl](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_partner.htm) generated from Salesforce which is consumed in above examples.

Comment: I think rolling your own should not be the first choice in most cases?

Comment: Yes, rolling your own code is not good if there are out of box feature matching with requirement, both options are given. @AdrianLarson

Comment: @Ashwin, i was thinking about the same solution (rest resource), but was not sure by the technical word webhook.. Thanks for confirming it.  Why my vendor keep calling it as webhook ?

Comment: Webhooks are generally open or authenticated URL, or you can say listeners at the end which accept the request from third party server. It has nothing different than a rest resource.

Answer (score 0):

There are **out of the box** APIs that allow external services to update records and don't require you to write a single line of `Apex` code:

- [SOAP API: Sample update Call](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sample_update_call.htm)
- [REST API: Update a Record](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_update_fields.htm)

You can also roll your own using:

- [Apex REST](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apex_workbook.meta/apex_workbook/apex_rest_1.htm)
- [SOAP Web Services](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_web_services.htm)

You should also read **Chapter 5 (Remote Call-In Pattern)** of **[Integration Patterns and Practices](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/integration_patterns_and_practices.pdf)**, which has much more detail than I can quote here.